# How to remove all duplicates from an array of objects angular?

Tags: javascript, typescript

`obj.arr = new Array(); obj.arr.push({place:"1",name:"true"}); obj.arr.push({place:"1",name:"false"}); obj.arr.push({place:"2",name:"false"}); obj.arr.push({place:"2",name:"false"}); obj.arr.push({place:"3",name:"false"}); obj.arr.push({place:"3",name:"true"});`

I'm wondering what is the best method to remove duplicate objects from an array. So for example, obj.arr would become...

`{place:"1",name:"true"}, {place:"2",name:"false"}, {place:"3",name:"true"}`

Comment: define duplicates

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Maybe instead of pushing in everything you should instead check if it already exist before pushing it into the array?

Comment: i use filter  to get the result but still not work

Comment: obj.arr = obj.arr.filter((value, index, self) =>
  index === self.findIndex((t) => (
    t.place === value.place && t.name === value.name
  ))
)

Answer (score 0):

The best method is

```
function unique<T>(list: T[]): T[] {
  return Array.from(new Set(list))
}
```

... but you haven't defined "duplicates". If they have some sort of unique key, that would be

```
function uniqueBy<T, K>(list: T[], getKey: (v: T) => K): T[] {
  return Array.from(
    new Map(
      list.map(e => [getKey(e), e])
    ).values()
  )
}
```

---

Generally if you dunno what's key, use `JSON.stringify` as `getKey`